# Invalid SOS parameters for sequential JPEG

Tags: php, exif

I' am getting this error when use `imagecreatefromjpeg` function.

```
Warning: imagecreatefromjpeg(): gd-jpeg, libjpeg: recoverable error: Invalid SOS parameters for sequential JPEG in C:\wamp\www\test\index.php on line 7
```

I researched, with this commands pass errors fine, works good.

```
ini_set("gd.jpeg_ignore_warning", 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE);
```

But I am wondering what is wrong this?

here my image exif data

```
Array
(
    [FileName] => 1.jpg
    [FileDateTime] => 1455186386
    [FileSize] => 1364340
    [FileType] => 2
    [MimeType] => image/jpeg
    [SectionsFound] => ANY_TAG, IFD0, COMMENT, EXIF
    [COMPUTED] => Array
        (
            [html] => width="2592" height="1944"
            [Height] => 1944
            [Width] => 2592
            [IsColor] => 1
            [ByteOrderMotorola] => 0
            [ApertureFNumber] => f/1.9
            [UserComment] => 
            [UserCommentEncoding] => UNDEFINED
        )

    [ImageWidth] => 2592
    [ImageLength] => 1944
    [Make] => samsung
    [Model] => SM-G920F
    [Orientation] => 8
    [XResolution] => 72/1
    [YResolution] => 72/1
    [ResolutionUnit] => 2
    [Software] => G920FXXU3COJ1
    [DateTime] => 2016:02:10 18:48:36
    [YCbCrPositioning] => 1
    [Exif_IFD_Pointer] => 226
    [COMMENT] => Array
        (
            [0] => File written by Adobe Photoshop¨ 5.0
        )

    [ExposureTime] => 1/25
    [FNumber] => 19/10
    [ExposureProgram] => 2
    [ISOSpeedRatings] => 200
    [ExifVersion] => 0220
    [DateTimeOriginal] => 2016:02:10 18:48:36
    [DateTimeDigitized] => 2016:02:10 18:48:36
    [ShutterSpeedValue] => 464/100
    [ApertureValue] => 1851/1000
    [BrightnessValue] => 33/100
    [ExposureBiasValue] => 0/10
    [MaxApertureValue] => 1851/1000
    [MeteringMode] => 2
    [Flash] => 0
    [FocalLength] => 220/100
    [MakerNote] => 0100 Z@P
    [UserComment] => 
    [FlashPixVersion] => 0100
    [ColorSpace] => 1
    [ExifImageWidth] => 2592
    [ExifImageLength] => 1944
    [ExposureMode] => 0
    [WhiteBalance] => 0
    [FocalLengthIn35mmFilm] => 22
    [SceneCaptureType] => 0
    [ImageUniqueID] => B05LLHA01PM
)
```

Comment: I know this is an old thread but I was looking around for a similar problem. Was your original image from a phone? Try searching the web as from another forum "This is libjpeg complaining about bad jpeg file structure. Not much can be done about it."

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can ignore the error with

```
ini_set ('gd.jpeg_ignore_warning', 1);
```

(this is the default since PHP 7.1, but not in older versions)

See http://php.net/manual/en/image.configuration.php

Comment: perfect solution.

Answer (score 4):

I also get the same issue

we used below code to fix this issue and it works for me.

```
$image = @ImageCreateFromJpeg($image_name);
if (!$image)
{
$image= imagecreatefromstring(file_get_contents($image_name));
}
```

Comment: Doesn't work for me also... I had to add extra @ in front of imagecreatefromstring :  
`$image= @imagecreatefromstring(file_get_contents($image_name));`