# Disable image parsing warnings in Tensorflow/Python

Tags: python, tensorflow, png, jpeg, suppress-warnings

I am parsing thousands of images with Python/Tensorflow/Keras.

The output of my program is "polluted" by constant warnings about images that actually seem to load correctly:

```
Invalid SOS parameters for sequential JPEG

W tensorflow/core/lib/png/png_io.cc:87] PNG warning: gAMA: gamma value out of range

W tensorflow/core/lib/png/png_io.cc:87] PNG warning: iCCP: known incorrect sRGB profile
```

How to disable these warnings?

For instance in PHP `ini_set ('gd.jpeg_ignore_warning', 1);` seems to be the [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39146520/226958) to the first one.

A solution that lets other information and other warnings get displayed would be welcome :-)

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if it works for PNG warnings but there is an environment variable that you can set called `TF_CPP_MIN_LOG_LEVEL` see:

https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/7652

and

https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/core/platform/default/logging.cc#L119

for more details.

Comment: I added `os.environ["TF_CPP_MIN_LOG_LEVEL"]="2"` and `tf.logging.set_verbosity(tf.logging.ERROR)`, that has made the PNG warnings disappear. The JPEG lines still show up, though, actually they are not log lines, they are outputted to the UNIX error output, so `2>/dev/null` can be a radical solution against them. Still, a less radical solution (that lets other information go through) would be welcome :-)

Comment: Sounds like the error comes from libjpeg directly and you can't suppress them apart from maybe compiling libjpeg yourself but maybe someone else has an idea.