# PHP GD error when calling imagecreatefromstring() on some images

Tags: php, image, gd

I found myself in front of that error on PHP when trying to call imagecreatefromstring() on some pictures (not all)

```
imagecreatefromstring(): gd-jpeg, libjpeg: recoverable error: Invalid SOS parameters for sequential JPEG
```

As recommended on other posts treating of this known problem, I tried to explicitly set error_reporting level and gd.jpeg_ignore_warning to friendly values. But this not work as expected, the error still showing and break the execution.

Here is the portion of code

```
error_reporting(E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE);
ini_set("error_reporting", E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE);
ini_set("gd.jpeg_ignore_warning", 1);
echo error_reporting() ." & ". ini_get("gd.jpeg_ignore_warning"); // expected " 32759 & 1 "
$sourceImage = imagecreatefromstring($decodedImage);
```

And the output :

```
32759 & 1
imagecreatefromstring(): gd-jpeg, libjpeg: recoverable error: Invalid SOS parameters for sequential JPEG
```

I don't understand why it is not working, any idea ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Invalid SOS parameters for sequential JPEG](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35337709/invalid-sos-parameters-for-sequential-jpeg)

Comment: No because the ini settings worked for him while they don't for me

Comment: Have you tested to ensure that your $codedImage is in the correct format? Perhaps try taking your string and feeding it into https://base64.guru/converter/decode/image/jpg and ensure that it is properly generating an image there. If not it's on your data image, not the imagecreatefromstring function.